# dplyr n() equivalent in Pandas?

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr

in `r` `dplyr` I can create a column index like this:

`df %>% mutate(id = 1:n())`

how can I do this in Pandas? I tried these:

`df['id'] = 1:len(df)`

`df['id'] = 1:df.iloc[-1]`

the `r`approach is particularly good because it works within groupings, so `n()` will count the length of a group_by grouping...

Comment: Range? np.arange? Kindly share sample dataframe with expected output

Comment: Cumcount may also be applicable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you want to do.

Assuming this input:

```
# R
df = data.frame(A=c(1,1,2,2,2));
```

```py
# python
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,2,2,2]})
```

To have a global counter:

```
# R
df %>% mutate(id = 1:n());
```

```py
# python
df['id'] = np.arange(len(df))+1
# or
df.assign(id=np.arange(len(df))+1)
```

To have a counter per group:

```
# R
df %>% group_by(A) %>% mutate(id2 = 1:n());
```

```py
# python
df['id2'] = df.groupby('A').cumcount().add(1)
# or
df.assign(id2=df.groupby('A').cumcount().add(1))
```

output:

```py
   A  id  id2
0  1   1    1
1  1   2    2
2  2   3    1
3  2   4    2
4  2   5    3
```

Comment: thanks! Can I ask, what is the deal with the `+1` and the `.add(1)`?

Comment: @stevezissou in python counting starts from 0, this is just to match the R way. You can remove it to have a count from 0 ;)

Answer (score 0):

With [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar):

```py
>>> from datar.all import mutate, n, seq
>>> from datar.datasets import table1
>>> 
>>> table1 >> mutate(id = seq(n()))
       country    year   cases  population      id
      <object> <int64> <int64>     <int64> <int64>
0  Afghanistan    1999     745    19987071       1
1  Afghanistan    2000    2666    20595360       2
2       Brazil    1999   37737   172006362       3
3       Brazil    2000   80488   174504898       4
4        China    1999  212258  1272915272       5
5        China    2000  213766  1280428583       6
```